# One or Multiple tables for storing Key Value Pairs?

Tags: sql, database-design, key

I'm trying to choose between these two table designs, performance is privilegied (querying with joints)

Multiple tables : each item (or key) has its own table

```
CREATE TABLE users_languages (
    "user_id" bigint not null,
    "language" integer not null,
    primary key ("user_id", "language"),
    foreign key ("user_id") references users ("user_id") on delete cascade
);
```

One KVP table: contains all items/keys

```
CREATE TABLE users_kvp (
    "user_id" bigint not null,
    "key" varchar not null, -- could be "language" or other
    "value" integer not null,
    primary key ("user_id", "key", "value"),
    foreign key ("user_id") references users ("user_id") on delete cascade
);
```

I presume that the last one would be slower for most operations, is it right ?  If yes, how much and when ?

Comment: Are you aware that this type of design (also known as Entity-Attribute-Value, or EAV) is generally considered to be an anti-pattern in relational / SQL databases? (There are circumstances where it's the only practical solution, but they tend to be the exception, not the rule.)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, what would be the good practise ? 
Setting a noSQL environment ? a Hstore (postgres) column ?
What about performance ? Any good reading about this ?

Comment: I suggest reading up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization , if you are not already familiar with the concept. Also, are you sure that a relational database is the best approach for your data storage requirements?

Comment: To some extent both examples could be considered as EAV, although the second example is closer to what is generally recognised as EAV. The first example seems like a cross between EAV and conventional relational structures, but without the advantages of either.

Comment: Okay I understand now.

Values per user and per item would be limited to 5 in my application. Should I avoid EAV and create new columns for the user table ? (user_language_1, user_language_n...

Comment: You **really** need to read up on normalisation. Are languages going to be the only data related to users? Is there no other data to be stored relating to your system? Are you sure that a relational database is the best approach for your requirements? Is this related to a specific business-related requirement or is it a purely academic exercise?

Comment: This is a business application.
Languages and 1 other item are related to user, not more (and will remain).
noSQL environment wouldn't be worth it IMHO, should I avoid EAV and go with a normalisation (users would contains 10 more columns) ? I thought this design would be slower comparing to EAV but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the question, it looks like a normalised, relational data structure would be best for your requirements. Such a table structure might look something like:

```
Users
-----
UserID (PK)
UserName
... (other attributes)

Languages
---------
LanguageID (PK)
LanguageName

UserLanguage
------------
UserID (PK)
LanguageID (PK)
```

You *could* put all your User's Languages onto the Users table (as Language1, Language2, etc) but this would be an example of [denormalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalisation) - in my opinion, from the information provided, it would be inappropriate for your requirements.

Comment: Interesting: 'EAV structures are like drugs: in small quantities and used in the proper circumstances, they can be beneficial. However, too much will kill you.'

Comment: @younes0: There's an interesting case study of what can go wrong with EAVs here: http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/